# Is there a way to search Stack Overflow with my website inputs?

Tags: discussion

I have a search bar that I would like the user to ask a question with, and it is to be searched using Stack Overflow. Is this possible?

Comment: Voted to move to meta. There might be some kind of search API in stackexchange that you can talk to.

Comment: Try this: http://www.google.com/search?q=%22your+query%22+site:stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

There is a *[Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/help)* app which enables cross-domain search of Stack Overflow:

[StackUnderflow.js: A JavaScript Library and Mashup Application](https://stackapps.com/questions/541/stackunderflow-js-a-javascript-library-and-mashup-application)

> StackUnderflow.js is designed to be used within your own sites, enabling you to easily include Stack Exchange information on your sites.
>
> It also adds the ability to search the content of questions by abstracting away an Ajax Google search for you. This enables some powerful capabilities, such as:
>
> Display questions that link to your blog.
>
> Display questions that link to the current blog article.
>
> Display questions related to keyword or tags on a bug tracking site.
>
> Display questions related to a feature directly from online documentation for your products.